# Property of an Object in an Array

Tags: javascript

i have an array with objects as elements:

```
var array = [{a:x}, {b:y}, {a:z}]
```

now i want to add for array[0] and array[2] an extra property

```
array[0].b = q;
array[2].b = q;
```

Is it possible to call it shorter?

```
array[0].b = array[2].b = q
```

Maybe also shorter then this?

Comment: Did you try?...

Comment: Did you try? What happened?

Comment: `var array = [{a:"x"}, {b:"y"}, {a:"z"}];
array[0].b = array[2].b = "q";
console.log(array)` works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could iterate the indices and create the property.

```js
var array = [{ a: 'x' }, {b: 'y' }, { a: 'z' }];

[0, 2].forEach(i => array[i].b = 'q');

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Not shorter but scalable

Comment: `let array = [{a:"x"}, {b:"y"}, {a:"z"}];
array[0].b = array[2].b = "q";` also works, but is not scalable much